# React: Map multidimensional array with different keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How could I map a multidimensional array with differents keys?
This is a example array similar: (my original array is obtained from ajax and PHP mysql query that's why I need to do this):

```
var products = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'John',
            phones: {
                sony:
                {
                  brand: 'sony',
                  model: 'z3'
                },
                samsung:
                {
                  brand: 'samsung',
                  model: 's7'
                }
              }

        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Mike',
            phones: {
                sony:
                {
                  brand: 'sony',
                  model: 'z1'
                },
                nokia:
                {
                  brand: 'nokia',
                  model: 'n8'
                }
              }

        }
      ];
```

If I try to map this array I get: 'Uncaught TypeError: product.phones.map is not a function':

```
const List = ({ products, addToCart }) => { 

  return (
    <div className="odds-3">
      <div className="odds">

        {products.map((product, index) =>
          <div key={index}>
            <p>{product.id} - {product.name}</p>
            <ul>
              {product.phones.map((phone, index) =>

                <li key={index}>{phone.brand} - {phone.model}</li>

              )}
            </ul>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

With this array (without phones keys), works fine:

```
 var products = [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'John',
                phones:
                    [{
                      brand: 'sony',
                      model: 'z3'
                    },
                    {
                      brand: 'samsung',
                      model: 's7'
                    }
                  ]
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Mike',
                phones:
                    [{
                      brand: 'sony',
                      model: 'z1'
                    },
                    {
                      brand: 'nokia',
                      model: 'n8'
                    }
                  ]
            }
          ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`products` isn't an array so the `map` function won't work. Try

```
{Object.keys(product.phones).map((phone, index) =>
 <li key={index}>{product.phones[phone].brand} - {product.phones[phone].model}</li>
)}
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, the phones property is an `object` not an `array` and therefore does not have the `map` function

The second one works `phones` is an `array`.

Comment: and how could I go through the array?

Comment: Well if `phones` can be an array then keep at as that and you're good to go. Otherwise you can loop over the keys in the object using the answer from @kind-user

Answer (score 0):

As others before me told you, `products` isn't an array and therefore you can't use the map function on it.

Although, you can use the `map` function from `lodash` library which you can use in order to iterate over an object keys/values:

```
import map from 'lodash'
{map(product, (value, key) =>
 ...
)}
```

For more info, read [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map)

Comment: very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays work slightly differently in JavaScript. In your case, a drop-in fix would be iterating over the values of the object, something like this:

```
{products.map((product, index) =>
    <div key={index}>
        <p>{product.id} - {product.name}</p>
        <ul>
            {Object.values(product.phones).map((phone, index) =>
            <li key={index}>{phone.brand} - {phone.model}</li>
            )}
        </ul>
    </div>
)}
```

While some browsers still lack support for `Object.values()`, the transpilation step should take care of this.

Note that it is generally not advisable to use indices as keys, as you might get [weird rendering bugs](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) should the ordering or the contents of your iterables change.