# How to clean a PHP multidimensional associative array to map with javascript es6

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a PHP multidimensional associative array like this:

```
$matchs = array(    
    '10689' => array(
        'id' => '10689',
        'sport' => 'Football',
        'player_1' => array(
          'id' => '22',
          'name' => 'Mike Oldfield',
          'odds' => array(
            'bookie_1' => '1.20',
            'bookie_2' => '1.21',
            'bookie_3' => '1.22'            
          )
        ),
        'player_2' => array(
          'id' => '122',
          'name' => 'Fran Sinatra',
          'odds' => array(
            'bookie_1' => '4.10',
            'bookie_2' => '4.11',
            'bookie_3' => '4.22'            
          )
        )
    ),
    '10829' => array(
        'id' => '10829',
        'sport' => 'Basketball',
        'player_1' => array(
          'id' => '522',
          'name' => 'Frank Black',
          'odds' => array(
            'bookie_1' => '2.01',
            'bookie_2' => '2.02',
            'bookie_3' => '2.04'            
          )
        ),
        'player_2' => array(
          'id' => '122',
          'name' => 'Freddie Mercury',
          'odds' => array(
            'bookie_1' => '1.87',
            'bookie_2' => '1.86',
            'bookie_3' => '1.85'            
          )
        )
    ),    
);
```

I need to pass that array to React App. Then I make something like this:

```
<?php echo json_encode($matchs, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); ?>
```

Then with `axios` (I have also tried with jquery and other libraries) I get the json file. Everything perfect for now.

The problem comes when I try to traverse the array. I get an error 'TypeError: xxx.map is not a function'. Thanks to this thread what has been achieved in part: [React: Map multidimensional array with different keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036181/react-map-multidimensional-array-with-different-keys/47036267#47036267)

The question is how could I remove the keys of this array to traverse without using `Object.keys`

I have tried `echo json_encode(array_values($matchs, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT))` , the problem is that it only eliminates the keys of the first level. In my array example 'player_1', 'player_2' and 'odds' remains.

Comment: The associative array in question is not valid. `'sport' => 'Football'` you are missing a `comma`. Is that a typo?

Comment: `Object.values` or `Object.entries`. May want Babel or a polyfill for older browsers.

Comment: Fixed, it was a transcription error

Comment: What is `xxx` in `xxx.map`?

Comment: `xxx` is an example, depending on the zone of the array I get the `odds.map error` or `matchs.map error`...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your associative array structure, I realise that the JSON form of `$matches` will look something like,

```
{"10689":{"id":"10689","sport":"Football", ...
```

and when you decode this JSON in javascript, it becomes an `object` and `object.map` is not a valid method call (as `.map` is only applicable for arrays and not objects).

you will probably have to use `Object.keys(<your_json>).map`.

If you don't need keys, you can use `Object.values(<your_json>).map`

Hope it helps.